# JOOQ Insert into select with large number of records

Tags: sql, bulkinsert, jooq

I'm trying to insert large number of records by selecting from a different table.

In the below example, BAR table has around 1 million records and trying to insert all those into FOO table. Is there a way I can do this efficiently with out the loader API or batch insert with JOOQ?

FYI, I'm trying to avoid the approach to load all the records in memory, so I'm not using the loader API which expects the JOOQRecords.

```
dslContext
    .insertInto(FOO)
    .columns(FOO.A, FOO.B)
    .select(
        select(A, B)
        .from(BAR))
    .execute();
```

Comment: The approach you're choosing is one of the most efficient: Let the database do all the work. What issues are you running into?

Comment: I'm using RDS Postgresql and when the query is executing the db process is terminated with this message "The database process was killed by the OS due to excessive memory consumption"

Answer (score 0):

This isn't strictly a jOOQ problem as you'd run into the same issues when writing the equivalent query in JDBC or even in a stored procedure. Such a bulk data transfer operation is usually the most efficient way to copy data between tables using SQL. There might be other tools available that bypass the SQL layer (e.g. `pg_dump`), but with SQL, this is optimal.

If you don't have enough resources to run everything in one go, you could partition your data set into several chunks using different techniques:

- By transferring data of individual date ranges
- By transferring data of individual ID ranges
- By using [keyset pagination](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/seek-clause/)

When partitioning your data as mentioned above, do also check if you can decrease the transaction size, e.g. to 1000 rows per commit. This isn't exact science, you'll have to find appropriate chunk and transaction sizes empirically for your specific system.

With all of these approaches, ACID is no longer guaranteed, so if your source data is modified during the move, you'll have to detect that somehow, and "fix it" (e.g by flagging rows that have been moved)

Or, just add more memory to the system.